# Convert escaped unicode string to bytearray

Tags: c#, unicode-escapes

My input string consists of a mixture of unicode escape characters with regular characters mixed in. Example:

```
String input ="\u0000\u0003\u0000\u0013timestamp\u0011clientId\u0015timeToLive\u0017destination\u000fheaders\tbody\u0013messageId\u0001\u0006"
```

How can I convert this into a bytearray or Stream?

Expected output is Byte[]

```
//                         t     i     m     e     s     t     a     m     p
{0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x13, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x61, 0x6d, 0x70, 0x11, ...}
```

Comment: To get the byte array, you don't need to read your file as text. Just use `File.Open` and `Read`.

Comment: @I4V But that would read the character `\\`` as a byte then `u` as a byte then `0` as a byte etc. I needed some sort of a converter to read the first 5 characters as 1 byte.

Comment: RaGe, No `\u0000` is just a string represantation of byte `0`. Although you accepted the below answer, I can say that you are on the wrong track. (Hint: Compare the length of the string and the binary file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
```

You can try it using:

```
Text = BitConverter.ToString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can simply cast each character to its equivalent byte value.

You don't say how to handle unicode characters with a value > 255, but assuming you don't have any of those:

```
input.Select(c => (byte)c).ToArray();
```

Note that for your specific example, `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input)` will produce the exact same byte array.

However, you're not saying you want the string UTF8 encoded, and since you're not showing unicode code points above 255, it's hard to tell exactly what you want.